# Clip path SVG not scaling in Firefox - working in other browsers

Tags: css, firefox, svg, clip-path

I'm trying to get my logo to work properly for all browsers, but I can't get it working in Firefox.

I'm using the transform:scale() property to grow the SVG.
I have tried everything from adding a viewbox and many other svg properties. I even just took an svg directly exported from Illustrator and hosted that, but all with no success.

The code to rescale the SVG looks as follows:

```
var resize = function () {
  var svgPath = document.getElementById('SVGID_1_');
  var scale = ((Math.min(2048,window.innerWidth) / 425)).toFixed(2);
  var scaleStyle = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
  svgPath.style.transform = scaleStyle;
  svgPath.style.webkitTransform = scaleStyle;
}
```

It's scaling properly everywhere (even on iOS browsers) but not in Firefox.

My code can be found live at: https://codepen.io/unrealnl/pen/agPpgy

Comment: It's dificult to say without your code However I suspect you don't use  `transform-origin` in the css. Depending on the `transform-origin` value you may need to use   `transform-box: fill-box`

Comment: Hey! Forgot to add a link to my code, you can find it here: https://terminarchgames.com

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.  You should not link to a live site, because when you fix that site, this question will no longer be useful to future readers.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the info.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau here is a link for future readers: https://codepen.io/unrealnl/pen/agPpgy, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to take advantage of `objectBoundingBox` value for the `clipPathUnits` property to be applied on `<clipPath />` element. This solution doesn't need `js` at all.

Should be something like this:

```
<svg class="svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
      <path d="..."></path>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

To then apply the mask as you are doing [here](https://terminarchgames.com), something like:

```
.elem {
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}
```

---

[Here](https://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/full/f74769b41be77006c38992ed51fc7591) is the full working example and [here](https://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/f74769b41be77006c38992ed51fc7591) the code details to play with.

#### Important advice

You have to re-export your `svg` to be compatible with the `clipPathUnits` props.

Quoting Sara Soueidan from [this useful article](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/)

> One important thing to note here is that when you use the `objectBoundingBox` value, the coordinates specified for the contents of the `<clipPath>` must be in the range [0, 1]—the coordinate system becomes a unit system, and the coordinates of the shapes inside a `clipPath` have to be fractions in that range.

So to reproduce the [demo](https://codepen.io/elrumordelaluz/pen/f74769b41be77006c38992ed51fc7591?editors=1100) I re open your `svg` using *Adobe Illustrator* (but could be any vector editor program) and scale/place the `path` into a canvas of 1x1 pixel, then re-exported and voilà!

Comment: thank you so much for the detailed answer. Even tough this "issue" is fixed in the next nightly as mentioned above by Robert, this would be an immediate  fix. However I did notice a scaling issue in Chrome now (gotta love web development) but Ill work that one out myself. Best

Comment: Cool. Where is that comment from Robert? However keep in mind you are firing a scale `function` on `resize` event that could play against performance, when you could solve the same thing using only `css`.

Comment: Weird, I think he removed his message for some reason. I did not check yet the nightly build, maybe it's not in there the fix and he decided to remove his messages. btw, do you have an idea why it's not scaling correctly in Chrome?

Comment: @ErikSombroek although there is a bugfix in the latest Firefox release that changes scaling I'm not sure it has an effect on this particular issue and I'm not sure whether Chrome or Firefox rendering is correct on the userSpaceInUse problem in the original question.

Comment: I'd seen that Sara Soueidan article already but your breakdown re: "canvas of 1x1 pixel" solved my issue. Thank you!! Wish I saw this sooner before pulling my hair out for 2 hours.